# IIS 7 URL Rewrite

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

How do I rewrite everything after the question mark (?) as one parameter?

For example, I have a url as: http://www.example.com?abcdefg/test/module?wiating4request

Notice after the first question mark we have another in the query string. I basically need to post to that url and I cannot modify the url so I need to make do with what is provided.

I saw something similar here: [How can I use mod_rewrite to remove everything after the ? (question mark) in a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018564/how-can-i-use-mod-rewrite-to-remove-everything-after-the-question-mark-in-a/2018653#2018653)

Keep in mind this is for IIS 7.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do this with a rewrite rule in case you only want to match URL's with just one question mark too many, like your example. You can then use this rule:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Clean extra question mark from query string" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^(.+?)(\?(.+))*$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{URL}?{C:1}&amp;{C:3}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you want to match an unlimited number of too many question marks I think you will need to revert to a [custom rewrite provider](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/804/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module/) as detailed in the linked article. You might then end up with something like:

```
<rule name="Clean extra question mark from query string" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/{URL}?{ReplaceProvider:{QUERY_STRING}}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```